# Insert and Update in same execution context from different list of custom objects

Tags: apex

Hi I have a problem where in I am inserting the records in one custom object and once its successful, I want to perform update on same custom object in same execution context.

The update operation which I want to perform is by taking lookup reference from another custom object which I am receiving in form of List. So I want to iterate through that list and want to get the field information and assign that information to 1st List which I have inserted and then update it.

Both are lists. I am getting this both list from different execution so I am stuck here.

I am not sure how to perform another operation using update. I mean how to form SOQL for update operation.

Custom Object A:
Field:
X
B - Look up Ref to another custom object
Z

Custom Object B:
Fields:
P
Q
R

When I perform Insert on A, I have list which inserts the records in bulk.

After insert I have list B which is lookup ref to A which I want to assign it to A and perform update on A.

Only thing is B is list and A expect single record at a time to be saved.

Let me know if you require more info. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can insert and update in a single context , i am not sure if I am able to understand the problem point. I can help you if I can see the code. Example you mentioned is very confusing